# GROUP BY AND RIGHT JOINS IN DB2

Tags: group-by, db2, right-join

```
Select p.prodCode,
       p.description,
       p.unit,
       SUM(sd.quantity) "Total quantity"
FROM salesDetail sd
RIGHT JOIN product p
    ON p.prodCode = sd.prodCode
GROUP BY p.prodCode
ORDER BY 4 DESC
```

Help! My Script is not running. I need to get the total quantity of every product but my group by is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the sum of the quantity per product in separate subquery, and then join this back to the original `product` table:

```
SELECT t1.prodCode,
       t1.description,
       t1.unit,
       t2.total_quantity
FROM product t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT p.prodCode, SUM(sd.quantity) total_quantity
    FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN salesDetail sd
        ON p.prodCode = sd.prodCode
    GROUP BY p.prodCode
) t2
    ON t1.prodCode = t2.prodCode
```

Note that I replaced the `RIGHT JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN` by switching the order of the joined tables in the subquery.

**Update:**

If you absolutely need to use a `RIGHT JOIN`, then just replace the subquery with this:

```
SELECT p.prodCode, SUM(sd.quantity) total_quantity
FROM salesDetail sd
RIGHT JOIN product p
    ON p.prodCode = sd.prodCode
GROUP BY p.prodCode
```

Comment: I need to execute my script using only RIGHT JOIN, can you please help me with that?

Comment: Hi Oliver, check my update, just swap the table order in the join and replace `LEFT` with `RIGHT`, that's it.

Comment: Hi Tim. Sorry, I forgot that I'm only allowed to use RIGHT JOIN. I can't use Inner Join. :(

Comment: You can replace the `INNER JOIN` with a `RIGHT JOIN`, it should make no difference in this case, because every product code should match.

Comment: Okay Thanks Tim. :)

Comment: Tim, t2."Total quantity" is not valid in the context where it is used, can you please help me.

Comment: @OliverSpicerPrudentino Just use `total_quantity` (one word) as an alias, and then refer to this in the outer query.